# problem with searching subdirs

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

I snaged this sub off the web to recursively search all the files including subdirectoires

If i point this sub to a large area ( ie mydocuments or C:) I get an error:

> The CLR has been unable to transition
>   from COM context 0x1f6c48 to COM
>   context 0x1f6db8 for 60 seconds. The
>   thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely
>   either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running
>   operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has
>   a negative performance impact and may
>   even lead to the application becoming
>   non responsive or memory usage
>   accumulating continually over time. To
>   avoid this problem, all single
>   threaded apartment (STA) threads
>   should use pumping wait primitives
>   (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and
>   routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

Here is the code
(I believe its because the sub is calling itself)

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {
                string hash = GetMD5HashFromFile(f);
                Dic_Files.Add(f, hash);
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
     }
     catch (System.Exception excpt)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like a fairly innocuous directory scanning routine.  Could you please post the call stack of the exception as well as the implementation of GetMD5HashFromFile(), if feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debugging problem.

according to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/ed6db6c8-3cdc-4a23-ab0a-2f9b32470d35/

What you are seeing is one of "Managed Debugging Assistants" (MDA) and can be disabled by Debug->Exceptions ... > Expand the MDA node and uncheck the box against contextswitchdeadlock .

Comment: does that really fix the problem? or does debugging problem mean that its only a problem while i am debuging?

Comment: Code loks like correct. Reference this tread http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vsnet.debugging/browse_thread/thread/1e4ac1010ae5920d/03ca1c82ea79287b?pli=1

It is all about debugger problem trying to detect deadlocks in multitreaded system.

Answer (score 1):

The GetFiles method has an override that allows for recursive searching.  I would try using that and see if your problem goes away...

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string f in files)
        {
            string hash = GetMD5HashFromFile(f);
            Dic_Files.Add(f, hash);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this option but it crashes if one dir goes wrong so its really not practical

Answer (score 0):

Try running that code in a separate thread so that you don't block your UI during the search.   [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(VS.95).aspx) is the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a recursive function, simply use one of the overloading of Directory.GetFiles

```
Directory.GetFiles(sdir, null, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: That's simpler code, nice call.  However, the problem he's having is that the search itself is taking too long and needs to be done on a separate thread.

Comment: I saw this option but it crashes if one dir goes wrong so its really not practical